# Javascript: change variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change an variable inside a function? I trying to archive an simply toggle function based on one preassigned value. Here the code and here http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/jLQyx/

```
<p onclick="testit()">CLick</p>
<p id="value">Value</p>   


var valuediv = document.getElementById("value");

function testit() {
    if (c == 1) {
        var c = 1;
        valuediv.innerHTML = c
    } else {
        var c = 0;
        valuediv.innerHTML = c
    }
}
```

Comment: if `c == 1` why are you then assigning `c = 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at how **[JavaScript uses Global Variables](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable)** here.

```
var valuediv = document.getElementById("value");
var c = 1;

function testit() {
    if(c === 1) 
    {
        c = 0; 
        valuediv.innerHTML = c
    } else {
        c = 1; 
        valuediv.innerHTML = c
    }
}
```

This fixes your code. You were creating new "c" variables in your if/else blocks due to prefixing them with "var".

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLQyx/2/

Comment: Uh, ok ahahah sorry for my dumbiness also thanks to all the other replies

Comment: Gotta start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var` keyword and write `c = 1` & `c = 0`. You're re-creating variable `c` inside the function instead of updating the global `c` variable.

```
var valuediv = document.getElementById("value");
var c = 1;

function testit() {
    if (c == 1) {
        c = 0;
        valuediv.innerHTML = c;
    } else {
        c = 1;
        valuediv.innerHTML = c;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLQyx/1/

Answer (score 1):

No need to use conditionals:

```
var valuediv = document.getElementById("value"),
    c = 1;
function testit() {
    c = +!c;
    valuediv.innerHTML = c
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLQyx/4/)

Comment: Nice thing but i must use itto compare that value and execute other code with if/else... no just print the value :D Thanks to you too

Comment: @AgeLonglife OK, but try to place identical statements in `if` and `else` outside the conditional, if possible.

Comment: but if I use "case/if" it would be something different